# Posting JSON using CURL then go to the posted page

Tags: php, json, curl

I have a set of php processing pages that interact together by passing data via get, but now I have to pass JSON between a couple of the processing pages and need the same functionality as when using GET.

The current working get method:

```
//The guts

header("Location: $moreprocessing_url/?userid=$id");

exit();
```

Then in the moreprocessing_url picks up:

```
$userid = $_GET[id];

//More guts

$something = 'important';

header("Location: $public_url/?something=$something");

exit();
```

So now in the first processing page, instead of sending a simple string, I need to send JSON - so I am using CURL to post the JSON - but after the post I would like the page being posted to to continue the processing and have the original page stop.  The same way the above code works but using CURL/post instead.  Maybe my understanding of CURL isn't strong enough and this just isn't possible?

My CURL:

```
$curl = curl_init($moreprocessing_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

exit();
```

So this returns to the current page where the CURL is happening and not the moreprocessing_url which I want -- is this possible?  Basically I want the page being posted to, to take over and the one sending the CURL to stop.

Comment: If its just about passing data from one page to another, can't you just use sessions? The `$id` variable (or your JSON) will never hit the browser.

Comment: These php processing pages are being called from another language that does the session id management, so was trying to avoid that..?

Comment: Salman A- I thought sessions were used to manage session ids of the current web app user -- can I just sessions to pass data around like in the above example?

Comment: You're right, sessions won't work in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're trying to do this:

1. Browser asks for **guts.php**
2. **guts.php** posts JSON-encoded data to **more-guts.php**
3. **more-guts.php** processes the posted JSON and returns a **301 moved temporarily** response; the new location being **public.php?something=important**
4. **guts.php** receives this response and relays it to the browser
5. Browser follows the redirect

If this is true then you need little tweaking to your cURL script. Something along these lines:

```
$curl = curl_init("url.php"); // the URL that processes your POST

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); // use POST method
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json")); // set POST header
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); // set POST body

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // send output to a variable for processing
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); // set to true if you want headers in the output
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); // set to true if you do not want the body
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false); // set to false if you want to see what redirect header was sent

$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($output);
```

Depending values used for `CURLOPT_HEADER` and `CURLOPT_NOBODY`, the `$output` variable will contain the response header, body or both (they're separated by two blank lines). If you want something from the header, you can use regular expressions to extract the desired header and send it to the browser.

OR you can echo the body should you choose to do so.

Comment: OK I get that, and tested and got that working.  Now what if in your example: guts.php was posting the {foo:bar} to public.php?  Can I exit() after the curl - and have my curl load the public.php?

Comment: I guess the simplest form of the question is: how can I get the {foo:bar} from my guts.php processing page to my public page where i can break the JSON down and display (I guess I'll use jQuery or something else for that).

Comment: I accepted because you did correctly answer what I asked, and I got it work - thanks.  But Do you have any insight as to how to get (pass the data) JSON from my php processing page to a public faceing page?

Comment: @bMon: sorry I didn't reply earlier. cURL allows you to POST data from your page to any another page on the server side. This also means that the response of the POST (header and body) is received on the server side. From that point you can decide what to do with it. You can forward the headers to the browser - or - you can capture the body and send it to the browser.

Comment: cont'd: In the above example, the target url will be your public page. The `CURLOPT_NOBODY`, `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` and `CURLOPT_HEADER` become unnecesasry (since you're not interested in the `Location` header anymore), just echo the content returned by your public page. This technique is sometimes called server side proxy script.